# Periscope dryer vent exper

Tags: dryer, vent

My dryer's vent tube is stuffed behind the dryer and preventing it from sitting closer to flush against the wall. I found this ["Periscope" dryer vent kit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Smart-Choice-0-18-in-Dryer-Periscope-Vent-Kit-5304484130/206740122) and was wondering if anyone had experience with these?

Do they work well?  Is performance an issue at all?

[image]

Comment: The current setup makes me think that he installer had complete disregard for human life...

Answer (score 1):

They work well. I find that it is best once you have the length set correctly you trim off some of the extra, bend a tab to hold the shape, and use foil tape on the inside seams and outside seams to seal them. This helps prevent leakage lint from trapping as much on the corners.

Comment: I agree. They work quite well when carefully installed. I have been using one for about 10 years with no problems. You should pull it out from time to time to inspect it for lint build-up.

Answer (score 1):

The periscope product description says it's about 4 inches wide so it would take up about the same space as an elbow.

In my diagram the blue are elbows and the red is the flex line. Seems to be the same amount of work given the limited working space and will cost less.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a few of these and they have worked well. You'll need to get your centerline to centerline measurement accurate and then adjust your vent to those measurements. Mount the vent to the dryer first. After securing it with the clamp, have someone slowly move the dryer back into place while you get on the floor and guide the vent into the wall connection. Secure the vent with the clamp.